# iOS UITableView CheckMark Appearing on Every Row

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to get the cells in my app to only display a checkmark on the rows whose title matches words in an NSMutableArray that is stored in NSUserDefaults.  My issue right now is that it is showing a checkmark on every app...even the ones that the row doesn't match anything.  Here is my code, and console logs.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {  
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *rowsarray = [defaults objectForKey:@"checkedrows"];
    NSLog(@"ORIGINAL%@", rowsarray);
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF contains[cd] %@",  entry.date];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [rowsarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
NSString *myString = [filteredArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSLog(@"The array %@", filteredArray);
    NSLog(@"The string %@", myString);


    if([entry.date isEqualToString:myString]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }



        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Papyrus" size:19];
        UIFont *cellFont2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Papyrus" size:17];
        cell.textLabel.text = entry.date;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = entry.articleTitle;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        cell.textLabel.font = cellFont;
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = cellFont2;

    return cell;
}
```

Console logs:

```
2012-12-20 11:02:53.793 5MWG[3615:c07] ORIGINAL(
    "Day 1: "
)
2012-12-20 11:02:53.794 5MWG[3615:c07] The array (
    "Day 1: "
)
2012-12-20 11:02:53.794 5MWG[3615:c07] The string Day 1: 
2012-12-20 11:06:23.851 5MWG[3615:c07] 2
2012-12-20 11:06:23.852 5MWG[3615:c07] ORIGINAL(
    "Day 1: "
)
2012-12-20 11:06:23.852 5MWG[3615:c07] The array (
)
2012-12-20 11:06:23.852 5MWG[3615:c07] The string 
2012-12-20 11:06:23.854 5MWG[3615:c07] 2
2012-12-20 11:06:23.854 5MWG[3615:c07] ORIGINAL(
    "Day 1: "
)
2012-12-20 11:06:23.855 5MWG[3615:c07] The array (
    "Day 1: "
)
2012-12-20 11:06:23.855 5MWG[3615:c07] The string Day 1:
```

As you can see, the only string returned is Day 1:.
However, even rows with entry.date = Day 2: are displaying checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either add an `else`, or re-write the `if` as a conditional, like this:

```
cell.accessoryType = [entry.date isEqualToString:myString]
?   UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
:   UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Otherwise, a cell with a check mark set would keep the accessory forever upon being "recycled".

Answer (score 3):

I didn't look too closely at your code, but if you dequeue with reuse identifier and you don't set cell.accessoryType to none, then every recycled cell that had a check in the past will have a check in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write:

```
if([entry.date isEqualToString:myString]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
if([entry.date isEqualToString:myString]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```